# SSLMode = verify-full на RDS DB instanse

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services

Я хочу включить обязательную проверку ssl сертификата пользователя при подключении к базе данных.

В документации прочитал, что в параметрах группы нужно установить параметры rds.force_ssl = 1 и ssl = 1.  Я это сделал.

Перезагрузил instance, однако я все равно могу подключится к базе данных без запроса сертификата.

Что я делаю не так?